# insert many rows with one static field and fields selected from another table

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

what i am trying to do is this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (id1, id2)
(
    SELECT id, 1 as id2 FROM Table2
)
```

except i CANNOT put '1 as id2' inside that select statement.

so, as an example, i sort of want this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (id1, id2 = 1)
(
    SELECT id FROM Table2
)
```

i'm putting this in a stored proc and the select statement is generated by linq2sql (passed as a text variable). I'd be happy to somehow get that 'id2' into the linq2sql command text, however the sql generated (correctly) only ever puts the actual Table2 columns in the query (being just 'id1').

and i really don't want to have to do some string formatting to insert the text ', 1 as id2' in the sql command text..

also i can't leave id2 as null as it's got a FK constraint on it.

Comment: A foreign key constraint doesn't prevent the insertion of NULL values.

Comment: could this be done somehow using tempdb? select ids only into tempdb, then from that move them into Table1 along with the id2?

Comment: @Mark - sorry i wasn't really clear with that comment. I don't want to put null values in there as they SHOULD always have the field id2 as data.

Comment: The constraints you've put on yourself with this question is what's preventing you from getting a good solution. Why can't you just put 1 as id2 into the query? Is linq2sql that inflexible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok got it:

```
create table #tmp
( id1 int)

insert into #tmp (id1)
(
    select top 10 id1 from Table1
)

insert into Table2 (id1, id2) 
(
    select id1, 5 from #tmp
)

drop table #tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (id1, id2) SELECT id, 1 as id2 FROM Table2
```

Comment: er.. i said 'i CANNOT put '1 as id2' inside that select statement'

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own sql with minor edit.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (id1, id2)
(
    SELECT id, 1 FROM Table2
)
```